# Is every matrix product of this form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Can every matrix product of two square matrices $AB$ be written as a linear combination of the matrices of the form $CC^T$?

I tried $C=A+B^T$ and some other matrices. Induction doesn't look like a good idea either. Can someone help please?

Comment: A matrix can be written as such a linear combination if and only if it is symmetric.  $AB$ will generally not be symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

No. The product matrix $AB$ is not necessarily symmetric, while $CC^T$ is symmetric, and so is the linear combination of symmetric matrices.